# Hive 0.10 OK FAILED: NullPointerException null self join

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, self

I have a problem with Hive 0.10. 
When I try to do a self-join , Hive gives me error as OK FAILED: NullPointerException null.

The query is:

```
select b.name,
a.name1,
a.name2,
a.name3,
a.name4,
a.name5,
a.name6,
a.name7
from table a left outer join (
select name, max (name2) as name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7
from table
group by name, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7) b on a.name2=b.name2
```

Table is a view.

Can you help me?
Thanks,
Angelo

Comment: can you show the sample input of table???

Comment: All fields are string. The table has 1.5 millions of rows.